# the proof for weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, markov-process

This is the text of proof of the law
[image]

I don't understand why when $n\to \infty$, $\frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2} \to +\infty$? isn't $\frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2}=\frac{1}{k^2}$? how come $\frac{1}{k^2}\to0 $?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense, the proof works precisely because a certain expression goes to 0 as n tends to infinity and yet you seem to be asking why it is that the expression tends to infinity. It doesn't, and nothing in the proof that you quoted says that it does.

Comment: I've assumed it to be a typo, and that he means either $\frac{1}{k^2}\rightarrow 0$ or equivalently $k^2\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

As I said, the WLLN is: under independence conditions as stated, for any **fixed** $\epsilon>0$ 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P\left(\left|\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_N}{n}-\mu\right|>\epsilon\right)=0.$$
Your forumla says that **for any $k$**:
$$P\left(\left|\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_N}{n}-\mu\right|>k\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\leq\frac{1}{k^2}.$$
So let $\epsilon$ be fixed and choose $k(n)$ such that $$\epsilon=k(n)\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Then you have that
$$k(n)=\sqrt{n}\frac{\epsilon}{\sigma},$$
where $\frac{\epsilon}{\sigma}$ is some positive **constant**.
Substituting this in the above formula gives, as in the suggested solution,
$$P\left(\left|\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_N}{n}-\mu\right|>\epsilon\right)\leq\frac{1}{n}{\frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2},}$$
and since $\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon}$ is a bounded constant, **independent of $n$**, and so also in particular $\frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$, the right hand side goes to $0$ as $n$ grows to infinity, giving the claim.

And indeed yes, $k=k(n)=\sqrt{n}\frac{\epsilon}{\sigma},$ grows to infinity for $n$ to infinity.

Comment: @boon heT The problem is that $\epsilon$ is related to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$
and as you said $k=\sqrt{n}\frac{\epsilon}{\sigma}$, so $k^2=n\frac{\epsilon^2}{\sigma^2}$ then $\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2}$, I don't know how the right side becomes $\frac{1}{n}{\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon},}$ (whithout square) as your one. Again, now matter with or without square, $\epsilon$ is related to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, can't tell the trend I think

Comment: my solution was missing the square, you are right on that one. I've corrected it. And again no: $\epsilon$ you **fix** at the start. Then $n$ varies, and so you pick the correct $k$, which varies wrt $n$... I don't know how I can make this more clear

Comment: Sorry, I just can't get the idea. The right side is $\frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2}=\frac{1}{k^2}$, and k is any number, I still don't get it why $\frac{1}{k^2}\to0$ when n $\to+\infty$, k and n is not related to each other

Comment: once you fix $\epsilon$, $k$ is not any number anymore. It is exactly $\sqrt{n}\frac{\epsilon}{\sigma}$. That's the point you are missing. And thus they **are** indeed related to eachother